# NiFi - CURL using Execute Stream Command

Tags: curl, apache-nifi, cloudera

I am having a problem where when I send the request using the ExecuteStreamCommand I think some formatting happens to the payload before the call gets sent to the SMM API. I tried escaping the quotes in the payload but still no luck.

Here are my configurations for the ExecuteStreamCommand:

Command Arguments Strategy: Command Arguments Property

Command Arguments: -X POST -H referer:${Referer} -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d  '{"newTopics": [{"name":"testing123","numPartitions":3,"replicationFactor":3}], "allTopicNames":["testing123"]}' --negotiate -u : -b /tmp/cookiejar.txt -c /tmp/cookiejar.txt http://SMM-HOSTNAME:8585/api/v1/admin/topics

Command Path: curl

Ignore STDIN: false

Argument Delimiter: " " (Space)

Right now it's giving me a 415 - Unsupported Media Type Error.

Can someone please help.

I tried escaping the quotes in the POST and leaving the quotes.

Comment: I would use InvokeHttp and skip the curl.  Use curl or postman to test the api end point, required headers, payload, etc.  Then duplicate in invokeHttp.

Comment: I ran into many problems with ExecuteStreamCommand and curl, and I can't use invokeHttp because the platform is a docker container that might get restarted without notice, and I have no control over the image, so I can't add the cert needed for the API I'm hitting — anyway . . . though I really didn't want to, I ended up spinning off a shell script with my curl command and just executing that. I'm now facing a similar problem just trying to ExecuteStreamCommand with "touch".